# Teradata SQL: Problem adding multiple rows into newly created table using CREATE MULTISET TABLE

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

Here is my query:

```
DROP TABLE table_name

-- Create the multiset table to store product line owner information
CREATE MULTISET TABLE table_name (
    Product VARCHAR(100),
    Owner VARCHAR(100),
    Email VARCHAR(100)
);

-- Insert sample data into the table
INSERT INTO table_name (Product, Owner, Email)
VALUES ('Product', 'Owner Name', 'owner.name@email.com'),
       ('Product1', 'Owner Name1', 'owner1.name@email.com');

-- Retrieving data from the table
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

Here is the error that I'm getting:

```
[Teradata Database] [3706] Syntax error: expected something between ')' and ','.
```

If I try running it with the second row it works. It doesn't like the comma at the end of the closing parenthesis.

Comment: Teradata doesn't support multiple rows of values like that.

Comment: Is there a work around?

Comment: Separate insert statements.  If you have a lot of them, and you are using BTEQ or SQL Assistant (assume it works in studio), look into Multi Statement Request